# dealing with xml information of uml digram

Tags: eclipse, uml, papyrus

## i am trying to manually add new attribute to class in my class diagram modeled in Papyrus

and the addition that i intend is on xml file of class diagram but i don't know how can i manage the class diagram model because every model in Papyrus consists of three files :

1-

.uml

2-

.notation

3-*.di

adding the information related to the attribute to only *.uml file  is not sufficient

My question is how can i manage those three file ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "manage the class diagram model."

However, you should not manage these files directly, but let the tool do so for you.

For your benefit:

The "di" file is just a pointer to the other two.

The "notation" file contains all the information about the diagrams, e.g., layout, elements shown, etc.

The "uml" file contains all the information about the semantic model, e.g., the UML elements that are part of your model, their properties, and their links, but no information about representation on diagrams.

Unless you are an expert in the serialization of these files, I would recommend you **never edit them directly**! Let the tool do that for you.